# How can I set the log format in Dancer2?

Tags: perl, dancer

I am trying to change the logging format to include the line number of the file for a Dancer2 app. The default does not seem to do this. If I add the line

```
log_format: "[%f--%l] %m"
```

(which seems correct based on the [Dancer2::Core::Role::Logger documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Core::Role::Logger)) nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`log_format` isn't a global configuration directive. It's specific to the particular logging engine you're using, so you have to put it in the [configuration section for that engine](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Config#Logger-engine).

For example, if you're using the [Dancer2::Logger::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Logger::File) engine:

```
logger: "File"

engines:
  logger:
    File:
      log_format: "[%f--%l] %m"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot.  I've also discovered that if there are other engines (like for session), they need to be nested in the same "engines" section.  I have a session engine and it appears that it needs to be done as

```
logger: Console
session: YAML

engines:
  logger:
    Console:
      log_level: debug
      log_format: "[%f----%l] %m"
  session:
    YAML:
      session_dir: /tmp/dancer-sessions
```

I had the session engine information and it appeared that the console engine information was overwritten.